# Why am getting Cannot read property 'poPanel' of undefined

Tags: html, typescript, angular8

HTML
I am adding an ordered list that loops through an array of objects and adds them based on an button click (i.e. A list of items)

Example:
1. Item 1
2. Item 2
3. Item 3

The items are adding fine. No problem here but...
When I add a "remove function" that deletes each item, it works and does in fact delete them but I am receiving the following error in the console.

Cannot read property 'poPanel' of undefined

```
<ol class="panelNumbers">
    <li *ngFor="let POpanel of POpanelList">
      <button class="removePObtn" (click)="removePO(poPanel)"><span class="k-icon k-i-close-circle k-i-x-circle" *ngIf="showClose"></span></button>
      <app-po-panels></app-po-panels>
    </li>
  </ol>
```

.TS

Here I have set an empty array for POpanelList and each item is pushed onto the array but when I try to remove the panel, I get an undefined value on poPanel in the removePO function

```
 async ngOnInit() {
        await this.getText();
        this.POpanelList = [];
    }

    /*Adding and Removing PO and SO Panels*/
    addPO() {
        this.POpanelList.push(
            { poPanel: this.newPoPanel }
        );
        this.showClose = true;
    }

    removePO(poPanel) {
        for (let i = 0; i < this.POpanelList.length; i--) {
            if (this.POpanelList[i]['poPanel'] === poPanel) {
                this.POpanelList.splice(i, 1);
            }
        }

        this.showClose = false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you execute `removePO` the for loop will start at `i=0` and next decrement `i--` resulting in `i` being equal to `-1`. Since a negative array index cannot exist `this.POpanelList[-1]` will return `undefined` and `this.POpanelList[-1]['poPanel']` will result in your error:

`Cannot read property 'poPanel' of undefined`

I believe the fix is to change `i--` to `i++` in your loop

```
    removePO(poPanel) {
        for (let i = 0; i < this.POpanelList.length; i++) {
            if (this.POpanelList[i]['poPanel'] === poPanel) {
                this.POpanelList.splice(i, 1);
            }
        }
        this.showClose = false;
    }
```